# Relationships between models with no IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

So I inherited a database and .NET project that uses SQL Server. And we are needing to connect to it via Rails.

The problem is the database is not designed very well and the relationships are non-existent (foreign keys, etc.)

Is there a way to relate tables via models that don't have an ID field or a clear "relationship?"  Take these tables for example:

```
Lunches (table)
---------------
Lunch_Guid (PK, varchar(32), not null)
Lunch_Name (varchar(50), not null)
Lunch_Key (varchar(50), not null) -- UrlSafe_base64 random string
....

Foods (table)
-------------
Food_Guid (PK, varchar(32), not null)
Food_Name (varchar(50), not null)
Food_Key (varchar(50), not null) -- UrlSafe_base64 random string

....

Tray (table)
------------
Tray_Guid (PK, varchar(32), not null)
Item_Key (varchar(50), null) -- "Make-shift relationship."
Tray_Key (varchar(50), not null) -- UrlSafe_base64 random string
...
```

In the specifications given to me, I need to pull all Trays with their corresponding lunches.  Item_Key "appears" to be a "relationship" to the Lunches table (which may or may not be there).  However, I have been told that a Item_Key can hold a single Food item as well.

As you can see, there is no "clear" indication what Item_Key contains (no type field in Lunches table).  However, I would like to be able to use the model structure of Rails to handle this.

By the way, I am NOT able to update the tables in anyway to accommodate Rails.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure associations to use different keys. Sounds like you might be able to define two associations: one assuming `Item_Key` points at `Lunches.Lunch_Key` and one assuming `Item_Key` points at `Foods.Food_Key`. You could then use a method to determine which association to follow (you'd need to decide which takes priority given you don't know an `Item_Key` will uniquely point to a lunch or food.

```
class Tray < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :food, foreign_key: 'Item_Key', primary_key: 'Food_Key'
  has_one :lunch, foreign_key: 'Item_Key', primary_key: 'Lunch_Key'

  def content_name
    if self.food.present?
      self.food.Food_Name
    elsif self.lunch.present?
      self.lunch.Lunch_Name
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

You could always provide a `name` method in both your `Lunch` and `Food` classes which might make things easier.

P.S. I'm not pretending you've not entered a world of pain trying to get a schema like that working with `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: To expand on this a bit, I have another set of tables in the same project similar to this. But, the other table has a _Key and field and ironically a _Guid relationship in the same table (no FK). in your answer above, you show the has_one relationship.  Am I able to have multiple relationships to the same table but using different FK/PK setups? Say one that "relates" via the _Guid and another that relates via the _Key fields but to the same two tables?  This database is horribly designed, but I'm trying to show that Rails is superior to data relationship than what they are currently using.

Comment: Yep, you can just call it something else: `has_one :keyed_food, class_name: 'Food', foreign_key: 'Item_Key', primary_key: 'Food_Guid'`. Hope the answer was useful.